# The name GridView does not exist in the namespace http://schema.microsoft.com/client/2007

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am experiencing a pretty weird issue in my Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight project. I cannot use ListView et GridView in my XAML. It gives me that error: "The name GridView does not exist in the namespace http://schema.microsoft.com/client/2007 "
I have the correspnding references into my project.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the alias of the namespace? Maybe you can also post some code so that we can be able to see. its likely to be

```
schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007
```

schemas not schema